# Find all generators for $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, direct-product

I'm looking for all generators $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5$.

I know I could do this by writing out all the elements and then going through and finding the generators by trial and error, but is there a faster way?

Comment: Find the generators for one and for the other and then do a direct product of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $4$ is composite, the generators of $\Bbb Z_4$ are $[1]_4$ and $[3]_4$ as both $1$ and $3$ are coprime to $4$; however, $5$ is prime, so $[1]_5, [2]_5, [3]_5, $ and $[4]_5$ are generators of $\Bbb Z_5$.

But $4$ and $5$ are coprime. What can you conclude from this?

> The number of generators of $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5$ is $2\times 4=8$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: are the generators: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) and (3,4)?

Comment: Precisely, @user520403! Well done!

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, user520403! Please don't forget to upvote and accept (click the $\checkmark$ button) this answer!